# Rails gives a InvalidAuthenticityToken error. If I reload the page it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Here's how my application works : `User uploads a photo > He gets redirected to a page with a list of photos > The user set titles and descriptions of photos and hit save`. Now sometimes when a user hit save Rails give `InvalidAuthenticityToken` error. But if the user reload the page before he hit save, Rails won't give the error and everything will work fine.

Why is it happening like this? I use devise and omniauth.

The form :

```
<%= form_tag update_submits_photos_path, method: :put do %>
  <% @submits.each do |submit| %>
    <div class="cont">
      <%= fields_for "submits[]", submit do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class='subDetails'>
            <%= f.label :title, 'Title :', class: "updLbl" %>
            <%= f.text_field :title, class: "updInp" %>
            <%= f.label :description, 'Description :', class: "updLbl" %>
            <%= f.text_field :description, class: "updInp" %>                
          </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Update All",class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg uploadedUp' %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

**Update** : I just updated to Rails 4.2 stable and now the problem have disappeared!

Comment: How does the form get submitted? It could be helpful if you can provide the code generating the form in the page.

Comment: @Domon Sorry, just added the code for the form :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are two paths you can follow in order to resolve the issue.

First is add following line:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: :the_action
```

to the corresponding controller, where `:the_action` is most likely `update`.

Second option is to add the token to your form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just updated to Rails 4.2 final and now the problem have disappeared!

Comment: @EApubs Cool! wait, they didn't release it yet, did they? I mean official stable 4.2

Comment: Yes they have :-) 2 days ago : http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/12/19/Rails-4-2-final/